# Boost undefined references cross compiling linux to windows

Tags: c++, linux, windows, boost, cross-compiling

I'm trying to cross compile from linux to windows using boost. I've already cross-compiled boost and I do have the DLL, but when I'm linking, I'm getting several undefined references :

> src/client/CommunicationHandler.o:CommunicationHandler.cpp:(.text+0x170): undefined reference to `boost::asio::io_service::io_service()'
>
> src/client/CommunicationHandler.o:CommunicationHandler.cpp:(.text+0x1b7): undefined reference to boost::asio::ip::address_v4::from_string(std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::allocator > const&)'
>
> src/client/CommunicationHandler.o:CommunicationHandler.cpp:(.text+0x1c7): undefined reference to boost::asio::ip::address::address(boost::asio::ip::address_v4 const&)'
>
> src/client/CommunicationHandler.o:CommunicationHandler.cpp:(.text+0x54e): undefined reference to `boost::asio::io_service::~io_service()'
>
> src/client/CommunicationHandler.o:CommunicationHandler.cpp:(.text+0x5c0): undefined reference to `boost::asio::io_service::~io_service()'
>
> src/client/CommunicationHandler.o:CommunicationHandler.cpp:(.text+0x97e): undefined reference to `boost::asio::io_service::run()'
>
> src/client/CommunicationHandler.o:CommunicationHandler.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio2ip14basic_endpointINS1_3tcpEEC1ERKNS1_7addressEt[_ZN5boost4asio2ip14basic_endpointINS1_3tcpEEC1ERKNS1_7addressEt]+0x2a): undefined reference to boost::asio::ip::detail::endpoint::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address const&, unsigned short)'
>
> src/client/CommunicationHandler.o:CommunicationHandler.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost4asio2ip16resolver_serviceINS1_3tcpEE7destroyERSt10shared_ptrIvE[_ZN5boost4asio2ip16resolver_serviceINS1_3tcpEE7destroyERSt10shared_ptrIvE]+0x20): undefined reference to boost::asio::detail::resolver_service_base::destroy(std::shared_ptr&)'

...etc

Why does the symbols are not in the DLL? What shall I do to make it link properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this make it works

#ifndef BOOST_SYSTEM_USE_LIB
# define BOOST_SYSTEM_USE_LIB
#endif